# mercurial alias: "option --config may not be abbreviated" error

Tags: configuration, mercurial

I have defined the following alias in my mercurial configuration.

```
[alias]
ci_s = ci --config phases.new-commit=secret
```

When I executed the command `ci_s`, I got the error:

> abort: option --config may not be abbreviated!

Not sure what's causing the error. My guess is the "=" sign between *new-commit* and *secret*. Is there any way to make this alias to work? Thanks.

Comment: This bug report explains why it's not supported (architectural issue, rather than a matter of principle) https://bz.mercurial-scm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2643

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I have got the solution to my question from the helpful Mercurial IRC. According to one of the core developers, mg, the error message is telling me that I cannot use --config in aliases. Instead, I can choose to use shell alias, `ci_s = !$HG ci --config...`, which would make Mercurial spawn a new child process. Since the commit process is quick, so I don't see any issue with spawning a new child process.

Comment: `env LANG=C hg --conf extensions.blackbox=! shelve -l` [newline?]
`*** failed to import extension hgext.blackbox: No module named blackbox` [newline?]
`abort: option --config may not be abbreviated!`